# Fresh Debian Install boots without GUI while Gnome being installed

Tags: debian, gnome, nvidia, gui

I installed a Debian (I've forgotten the exact Version) from a DVD onto a fresh system.
Everything seemed to be fine. The grub menu opened and I was able to choose between Debian and Debian Recovery. Both of these choices stopped the boot process at some point (fb: conflicting fb hw usage nouveaufb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver).
With the help of (nouveau.modeset=0) Debian seems to boot correctly. It appears a black screen with the blinking _ cursor.
Pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 opened a full screen console.
Everything seems to work except for the GUI.

I tried `sudo startx` but this gives me an Error

> Fatal server error: no screens found

I already searched the WEB and figured out it might have something to do with the Nvidia Card (GTX 950)

I'm open to all new attempts on how to resolve this.

Comment: Could you find out the version of Debian you've installed? Do you at least know if it was Jessie or testing/stretch? You could run `lsb_release -a` to find out. Or `cat /etc/debian_version` if the former doesn't work.

Comment: It's Debian 7.11 (wheezy). That seems to be almost outdated.

Comment: 7.x is Wheezy, which is the old release. The current one is Jessie (8.x), and Squeeze (9.x) will probably be out within a few months. IOW, unless you have some peculiar needs, I think your first step ought to be to install Jessie... Since its a fresh install, you could just reinstall with Jessie discs, or alternatively, you can upgrade following the Jessie release notes @ https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/releasenotes — I'm guessing it'll be easier to get working on Jessie, if it doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: (BTW: Wheezy was released May 2013, and since then has only had bugfixes—just to give you an idea of the age of what you've installed)

Comment: Okay, thanks, than I'll just install it again. What have I learned? Always write the version ono the disc as well . . .

Comment: Yes, indeed! I hate it when I find a pile of unlabaled CDs/DVDs... Especially since invariably it's my fault for not getting the marker out :-(

Comment: Well atleast it said DEBIAN on it ;)